# Typing for a Python function that takes a generic class and returns a specific instance of that class

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, generic-function

Suppose I have a class definition like this:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

class Collection(Generic[T]):
    ...
```

I want to create a function like this (Data is some container type):

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

def get_data(typ: Type[T]) -> T[Data]:
    return typ[Data](...)
```

Basically, I would like this function to accept a generic type with one type variable and return instance of that type but with type variable set to some other type

Comment: Yeah, you are [not alone](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548). Let's hope we get those higher-kinded types soon. For now, you're out of luck.

Comment: If you have control over `Collection` class, you may try `returns` library; here's a great [documentation page](https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/hkt.html), that explains HKT concept for python, and [the article](https://sobolevn.me/2020/10/higher-kinded-types-in-python) by `returns` maintainer with more details and "how did I come with this solution" explanation, which may be even more interesting than the final result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Generic (higher-level) type variables in type hinting system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118095/how-to-use-generic-higher-level-type-variables-in-type-hinting-system)

Comment: @SUTerliakov Unfortunately I do not have control over `Collection` class. But I read about `returns` library and it was really interesting. I hope we will get higher-kinded types soon.