# Python and MyPy - TypeVar bound by protocol with another bouned TypeVar

Tags: mypy, python-typing

is there any option how to define typing to achieve that MyPy evaluates `data_one` as instance of class `DataOne` and `data_two` as instance of class `DataTwo`? Currently I get Any and some MyPy errors with `--strict`.

There is code example. [Here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=6dcd8a3bfae209e740e2563b53428ddd) is same code on Mypy Playground.

I used Python 3.10.6 and MyPy 1.3.0

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Generic, Protocol

import dataclasses


# Interfaces #
class DataInterface(Protocol):

    @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        ...
    
    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        ...


T = TypeVar("T", bound=DataInterface, covariant=True)


class BuildInterface(Protocol[T]):

    @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        ...

    def to_data(self) -> T:
        ...


R = TypeVar("R", bound=BuildInterface[T])


# Function #

def my_fce(builder: R) -> T:
    return builder.to_data()


# Implementation - One #

@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
class DataOne:

    value: int
    name: str
    cfg: str


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
class BuilderOne:

    value: int

    def to_data(self) -> DataOne:
        return DataOne(self.value + 1, "foo", "my_cfg")


builder_one = BuilderOne(1)
data_one = my_fce(builder_one)

# Return Any - should return instance of DataOne
reveal_type(data_one)


# Implementation - Two #

@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
class DataTwo:

    value: int
    name: str
    num: int


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
class BuilderTwo:

    value: int

    def to_data(self) -> DataTwo:
        return DataTwo(self.value + 1, "foo", 1)


builder_two = BuilderTwo(1)
data_two = my_fce(builder_two)

# Return Any - should return instance of DataTwo
reveal_type(data_two)
```

Thank for any advice.

Comment: You cannot define a higher-kinded typevars in python, at least natively. See [relevant `python/typing` issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548) with a proposal. There's awesome [`returns`](https://pypi.org/project/returns/) library, maybe it will work for you ([documentation here](https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/hkt.html))

Comment: Ah, sorry, your case is much simpler: no need to define `R` at all, you can just `def my_fce(builder: BuildInterface[T]) -> T:`, because you don't return anything related to `R` specific class. Your function works for arbitrary `BuildInterface` implementation, and return type is not dependent on the actual class passed in. [Like this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=3cec370b607f5f2ee27940de1b161bc5), gist mine.

Comment: @SUTerliakov thank you for advice. Unfortunately my example was too simplified. What I am trying to do is [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=8632f20889ce72190b22b46f2504c6d1)

Comment: Well, you still can get rid of `R` and get your desired typing outcome: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=47e84750788e0b33cf31f3ecf9f4e3ed. The only constraint you cannot express (no such option exists in python type system, you're out of luck for it) is `BuildInterface[T[S], S]]` (first generic depends on another) - the only solution is fallback to `BuildInterface[T, S]` where `T` is bound to `DataInterface[Any]` and not `DataInterface[S]`. The rest seems to work as intended.

Comment: @SUTerliakov this is what I was afraid of. Thank you for confirmation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Generic (higher-level) type variables in type hinting system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118095/how-to-use-generic-higher-level-type-variables-in-type-hinting-system)