# How do I type a class in python that depends on another generic type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

The easiest way to ask this question is to show what I am trying to accomplish

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

ID_T = TypeVar("ID_T", int, str)


class BaseModel(Generic[ID_T]):
    def __init__(self, id: ID_T) -> None:
        self._id: ID_T = id

    @property
    def id(self) -> ID_T:
        return self._id


MODEL_T = TypeVar("MODEL_T", bound=BaseModel[ID_T])


class BaseModelRepository(Generic[MODEL_T, ID_T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._db: dict[ID_T, MODEL_T] = {}

    def add(self, model: MODEL_T) -> None:
        self._db[model.id] = model

    def get(self, id: ID_T) -> MODEL_T | None:
        return self._db.get(id, None)


class MyStrModel(BaseModel[str]):
    @property
    def foo(self) -> str:
        return "foo"


class MyStrModelRepository(BaseModelRepository[MyStrModel, str]):
    pass


my_str_model_repo = MyStrModelRepository()
my_str_model = MyStrModel("id")
my_str_model_repo.add(my_str_model)

my_other_str_model = my_str_model_repo.get("id")
print(my_str_model.foo)
```

Basically, I am having a hard time figuring out the correct way to type the `BaseModelRepository` so that the `id` parameters and `model` return types are all correct and pass mypy without issues.

I'm probably missing something really obvious, and will no doubt hang my head in shame once I see the solution.

Comment: See comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344074/python-and-mypy-typevar-bound-by-protocol-with-another-bouned-typevar). What you intend is not possible; can't close as dupe, because that question has no answer. Maybe there are older duplicates.

Comment: Oh, yes, there are dupes. See the suggested one.