# How do I assign a generic return type to the method of a generic typed class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, mypy

In the code below, `GameObjects.to_dict` needs to reflect the generic for a `TypeDict`, depending on the type that has been passed to `GameObjects`. In this specific example, mypy gives an error:

`line 37: error: List comprehension has incompatible type List[GameObjectDict]; expected List[D]  [misc]`

I want to avoid having to create a concrete class for `Assets` just for the purpose of defining the return type there - I potentially have a lot more such containers which will be functionally identical.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generic, TypedDict, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="GameObject")
D = TypeVar("D", bound="GameObjectDict")


class GameObjectDict(TypedDict):
    name: str


class AssetDict(GameObjectDict):
    path: str


class AbstractGameObject(ABC, Generic[D]):
    @abstractmethod
    def to_dict(self) -> D:
        raise NotImplementedError


@dataclass
class GameObject(AbstractGameObject, Generic[D]):
    name: str

    def to_dict(self) -> GameObjectDict:
        return GameObjectDict(name=self.name)


@dataclass
class GameObjects(Generic[T]):
    items: dict[str, T] = field(default_factory=dict)

    def to_dict(self) -> list[D]:
        return [item.to_dict() for item in self.items.values()]

    def add(self, item: T):
        if item.name in self.items.keys():
            raise KeyError(f"{item.name} already exists")

        self.items[item.name] = item


@dataclass
class Asset(GameObject):
    path: Path

    def to_dict(self) -> AssetDict:
        return AssetDict(**super().to_dict(), path=str(self.path))


Assets = GameObjects[Asset]()
```

Comment: What you want in general is higher-kinded typevar. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118095/how-to-use-generic-higher-level-type-variables-in-type-hinting-system. If you don't need to be this specific, you can forget the wrapper type and depend on typeddict type only: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=cc545c756c8063367cafad2def83fcbd

Comment: Awesome thanks for the pointers, sometimes the problem is so niche and has a particular name that just getting the name is the first step. I'll investigte the HKT approach