Type hinting to return the same type of Sized iterable as the input?
The following code works, but depending on how I fix the type hinting, either PyCharm or mypy complains about it.  I've tried Sized, Iterable, and Collection for the type of S.
T = TypeVar("T")
S = TypeVar("S", bound=Collection[T])


def limit(i: S, n: int) -> S:
    """
    Limits the size of the input iterable to n.  Truncation is randomly chosen.
    """
    if len(i) <= n:
        return i
    return type(i)(random.sample(list(i), n))

What I want is something like random.sample with the following two properties:

If n > len(i), return i instead of throwing an error
The type of Collection of the output should be identical to the input.  list[int | str] in = list[int | str] out; set[float] in = set[float] out.

If there's already something like this in the standard library, I'll use that.

You don't need to specify T here; S, being bound to Collection[Any], can already take on any kind of collections (e.g., list[int | str] is a subtype of Collection[Any]). However, you can't guarantee that an arbitrary subclass of Collection will have a constructor accepting list[*], so the type(i)() call will always be an error (not to PyCharm, though). Does that answer the question?

(and it isn't possible to bind T to S if you really need to have T in the signature - higher-kinded types aren't a thing in python, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118095/how-to-use-generic-higher-level-type-variables-in-type-hinting-system)

Can the collections be limited to list and set, as you described above?

@CharlesKnell As far as I'm aware, yes.  At least everywhere I would need such a function.  There may be a frozenset in there somewhere, too.

@InSync Since accepting list[*] as a constructor isn't guaranteed by the typing.Collection, could a union of list | set | frozenset work in place of Collection?

It sure can. I'll write an answer.

You don't need T here. Just by declaring a bound of Collection[Any], S can take on any "actual" collection form:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
def limit[S: Collection[Any]](i: S) -> S: ...

reveal_type(limit([1, 2, 3]))             # list[int]
reveal_type(limit({1, 2, 3}))             # set[int]
reveal_type(limit(frozenset({1, 2, 3})))  # frozenset[int]

However, Collection doesn't guarantee anything about its constructor, so invoking type(i)(list(...)) is an error. Replacing Collection[Any] with list[Any] | set[Any] | frozenset[Any] should help eliminating this error:
def limit[S: list[Any] | set[Any] | frozenset[Any]](i: S, n: int) -> S: ...

In reality, it doesn't:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
reveal_type(type(i))  # type[S]

# pyright => fine
# mypy => error: Incompatible return value type (got "list[Any] | set[Any] | frozenset[Any]", expected "S")
return type(i)(random.sample(list(i), n))

This is either a bug or limitation of Mypy, because a type[S] should produce a S instead of its bound on construction. For now, ignore this with a # type: ignore.
In conclusion:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
from typing import Any
import random

def limit[S: list[Any] | set[Any] | frozenset[Any]](i: S, n: int) -> S:
    if len(i) <= n:
        return i
    
    return type(i)(random.sample(list(i), n))  # type: ignore[return-value]

reveal_type(limit([42, '', 3.14], 0))             # list[int | str | float] / list[object]
reveal_type(limit({42, '', 3.14}, 0))             # set[int | str | float] / set[object]
reveal_type(limit(frozenset({42, '', 3.14}), 0))  # frozenset[Any] / frozenset[object]

type SomeComplexUnion = list[int | str | float] | set[int | str | float]
v = cast(SomeComplexUnion, [42, '', 3.14])

reveal_type(v)                                    # SomeComplexUnion
reveal_type(limit(v, 0))                          # SomeComplexUnion

Pre-PEP-695 syntax:
S = TypeVar('S', bound = list[Any] | set[Any] | frozenset[Any])

def limit(i: S, n: int) -> S: ...


Thank you for adding the pre-PEP695 syntax.  The project I'm working on is keeping 3.10 compatibility for now.  Worth noting to myself for future reference that frozenset is NOT a subclass of set, so both options need to be included in the union.

The following code fills your stated requirements for list and set:
import random
from typing import TypeVar, Union, Sized, Iterable


def limit(i: Union[TypeVar, Sized, Iterable], n: int) -> Union[TypeVar, Sized, Iterable]:
    if type(i) is not set and type(i) is not list:
        return i
    if len(i) <= n:
        return i
    return type(i)(random.sample(list(i), n))


my_list_of_ints = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
out = limit(my_list_of_ints, 3)
print(out)

my_set_of_ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
out = limit(my_set_of_ints, 3)
print(out)

my_list_of_floats = [1.2, 2.2, 3.3, 4.1, 5.6, 6.7, 7.8, 8.5, 9.3, 10.2]
out = limit(my_list_of_floats, 3)
print(out)

my_list_of_strs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
out = limit(my_list_of_strs, 3)
print(out)

my_set_of_floats = {1.2, 2.2, 3.3, 4.1, 5.6, 6.7, 7.8, 8.5, 9.3, 10.2}
out = limit(my_set_of_floats, 3)
print(out)

my_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
out = limit(my_tuple, 3)
print(out)


Is this AI-generated? Union[TypeVar, Sized, Iterable] doesn't seem like something a human would write.

No. I had to add Sized and Iterable to eliminate pycharm flagged errors.
